# Why are black holes black?

Tags: gravity, visible-light, black-holes, speed-of-light, gravitational-redshift

If heard two explanations for this. One explanation is that the gravity is so strong that space is being stretched inward faster than the speed of light and thus no photons could possibly escape. The other explanation I have heard is that photons can escape but that they become "red shifted into oblivion".
Can someone explain this to me? Are these actually the same explanation?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8477/why-cant-light-escape-from-a-classical-black-hole